# Creating an own class and start it

Tags: c#

I want my own Class to start but it seems not to be working.

My Class is:

```
namespace Ts3_Movearound
{
    class TS3_Connector
    {
        public class ccmove : EventArgs
        {
            public ccmove(int clid, int cid)
            {
                this.clid = clid;
                this.cid = cid;
            }
            public int clid;
            public int cid;
        }

        public event EventHandler runningHandle;
        public event EventHandler stoppedHandle;
        public event EventHandler RequestMove;

        bool running = true;
        public Main()
        {

            using (QueryRunner queryRunner = new QueryRunner(new SyncTcpDispatcher("127.0.0.1", 25639)))  // host and port
            {
                this.runningHandle(this, new EventArgs());
                while (running == true)
                {
                    this.RequestMove(this, new EventArgs());
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
                }
                this.stoppedHandle(this, new EventArgs());
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

and i call it this way:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TS3_Connector conn = new TS3_Connector();

        conn.runningHandle += new EventHandler(started);
        conn.stoppedHandle += new EventHandler(stopped);
    }
```

but it seems that the Class never starts correctly. The runningEvent never gehts fired, also the stopped and the Request. How can i run this Class now?

Comment: Why do you think it should work? You just created an instance. The `Main` method never gets called.

Answer (score 0):

The lifespan of your conn object ends when button1_Click has returned. You should declare conn in the class scope.

```
TS3_Connector conn = null;

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    conn = new TS3_Connector();

    conn.runningHandle += new EventHandler(started);
    conn.stoppedHandle += new EventHandler(stopped);
}
```

`TS3_Connector` itself does nothing. You should explicitly call `main()` (please rename the function to something understandable)

Comment: Uhm.. can you also tell me how i can run this Class in an own Thread?